# Loop doesn't work in C programming

Tags: c, file, fgets

I want to code a program that scans each line and print it. Also this process should keep on when the specific line was detected. Here is my file content :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

and the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
FILE *file;
int main(){
    file=fopen("numbers.txt","r");
    char line[10];

while(1){
         fgets(line,10,file);
         printf("%s \n\n",line);
         if(strcmp(line,"6")) break;
}

    fclose(file);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But loop doesn't work and print only first line. Where is the problem?

Comment: what error are you getting and where?

Comment: Do you understand strcmp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
FILE *file;
int main(){
    file=fopen("numbers.txt","r");
    char line[10];

    while(1){
             fgets(line,10,file);
             printf("%s \n\n",line);
             if(!strcmp(line,"6\n")) break;
    }

    fclose(file);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

You had two problems, first strcmp returns 0 if strings are equal, second fgets returns new line mark '\n', so you have to match it too.

Answer (score 6):

`strcmp` returns non-zero if the strings do *not* match, and zero if they do.

Change your test:

```
if( 0 == strcmp(line,"6") ) break;
```

Comment: I wish there were a special kind of downvote for "Made zero effort to consult any kind of documentation"... well spotted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `if(! strcmp(line,"6")) break;`  (strcmp returns 0 when the strings are equal)

Comment: Even that wouldn't work because fgets() leaves the newline in place.